# Getting started with ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have been using ArcGIS for some time and am playing around with arcscene for the first time. I am having trouble getting started. When I add a DEM to a blank project it renders as a uniform grey, blank obliqued square. If I use the info tool the values are in the range of valid elevations (ex: ranging from 80 - 2400). Strangely, once I use the info tool on the raster it displays as a uniform red. The same raster works as expected for a DEM in ArcMap. I have only the raster loaded in a blank project. The original Dem is an img format in a gcs coordinate system (downloaded from national map). I have tried reprojecting it and saving it in other formats with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make your data available?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.  
Try this link for the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gomUq9BTjo6k1WnaRLN2NgT-SD4DRG8B/view?usp=sharing
The following link is to a screen shot of what I am seeing in ArcScene. I can extrude the surface but have not been able to get it to render according to the symbolism in the TOC. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1galXTMjTNSLwTsTJz2hnSMDhFOiq6t0I/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance for any help you might offer.

Answer (score 1):

@Mark-Neal, I am able to display, render base heights, and alter the symbology of both your vector and raster data with ArcScene v10.5. I did not have to to re-project these data.

[image]

Using the identify button on these data returns the expected values and did not alter the color of the data.

Check that your *Properties-Symbology-Stretch* values are not set in such a way to render your image oddly. Here I am displaying your data with no stretch and I get a uniform color despite the color ramp choice.
[image]
[image]

If stretch is not your issue then consider re-installing ArcScene and ensure your computer has sufficient memory, and graphics card power, to use ArcScene.

Comment: Thanks so much for demonstrating that the data is not the issue and for your suggestion that the stretch might be the answer.  The stretch was set for the default standard deviations.  based on your results I looked deeper into my configuration.  I have discovered that disabling my graphics acceleration solves the issue.  I can work with it that way and research what I might change in my accelerator configuration to fix the issue.  Thanks again.